# Validate if data contains data from another table before delete

Tags: c#, validation

I need to validate a Parameter if it contains any values before I delete it. The Parameter is in another table and values are in another table.
I am trying this by using lambda expression, but just can't find the right way.
This gets the data from CalculationParameters table:

```
Factory.Definitions.CalculationParameters.List(); // List() lists all the data.
```

And this gets the data from CalculationParametersValues table:

```
Factory.Definitions.CalculationParametersValues.List(); // List() lists all the data.
```

Now if the "Id" (from CalculationParameter) equals to "CalculationParameterId" (from CalculationParametersValue) means that CalculationParameter contains values and I can't delete it.

Does anyone have any idea to help me out here ?

Answer (score 0):

if I understand that you want to check if Ids in CalculationParameters exist in CalculationParametersValues

you can try this

```
bool exist =Factory.Definitions.CalculationParameters.List()
            .Any(a=> Factory.Definitions.CalculationParametersValues.List().Any(b=>b.Id ==a.Id))
```

Comment: This happens:

Compile-Time Error : 
The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collection.Generic.List<Project.Folder.Project.Folder.Class>.Contains(Project.Folder.Project.Folder.Class)' has some invalid arguments

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want to remove all the CalculationParameters that have no records in CalculationParametersValues. If so, try something like this :

```
CalculationParameters.RemoveAll(p=> !(CalculationParametersValues.select(c=> c.CalculationParameterId)).contains(p.CalculationParameterId))
```